# Getting the response status code from node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I wanted to get the status code of the soap response in the client getRoleListOfUser function in the nodejs app.

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                reject ({ error: true });
            }
            client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('admin', 'admin'));
            client.getRoleListOfUser(args, function(err, result) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    reject ({ error: true });
                }
                console.log('success');
                resolve ({ message: result });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Result just send the response body data. success or failed ( 200 or 500 it just send the response body only)

Comment: can you try  function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) and see what's in soapHeader ?

Comment: soapHeader  ==> undefined, raw does show the response body